# CocoaPods ShareKit install issue

Tags: sharekit, cocoapods

I try to install ShareKit 2.2 using CocoaPods.

In command line I enter next:

```
touch Podfile
open -e Podfile
```

Edit my Podfile with lines below:

```
platform :ios, '5.0'
pod 'ShareKit', '~> 2.2'
```

Save file and enter `pod install`

After line `Installing ShareKit (2.2)` command line tool asks me to enter github account information. I have entered my account and got this message below:

```
[!] Pod::Executable clone  --mirror "https://github.com/dkuhnke/ShareKit.git" "/Users/developer/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/GitHub/a45caba117704c3f4cfa5f478a14e9305d2d5e9f"

Cloning into bare repository '/Users/developer/Library/Caches/CocoaPods/GitHub/a45caba117704c3f4cfa5f478a14e9305d2d5e9f'...
fatal: https://github.com/dkuhnke/ShareKit.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack not found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The maintainers of ShareKit decided to remove the [tag references](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/tags) that were used for the specs. Currently they want to be removed from the CocoaPods specs repo for now https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/pull/2280

I would recommend installing via their instructions https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/wiki/Installing-sharekit

**Edit:** I have just removed the 2.1 and 2.2 specs https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/commit/c7ba46164cd76ef3a34a4036f2f3889ee0e0187c

The 2.0 spec is still available but you may still consider the official install instructions.

**Update:**

A ShareKit version 2.3 spec has been added to the repo if you still want to install ShareKit with CocoaPods https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/commit/e7b99c9913be9e8b31ea846a98a60f8f25acbd64

Answer (score -1):

You are having this issue because your project path contained single quotes or spaces.

This issue has been already [reported to cocoapods](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/1344).